# The output from Scrapy is not being stored in database by pymssql

Tags: python, scrapy, pymssql

I am trying to get data using scrapy. It is not showing any error but still not getting any result. Can someone please help?
Below is the code I am using.

## Spider

```
import scrapy


class SecSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Sec'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sec.gov']
    start_urls = ['https://www.sec.gov/litigation/litreleases.shtml']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//*[@id="mainlist"]//tr')[2:]
        for row in rows:
            link = row.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
            number = row.xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first()
            date = row.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').extract_first()
            title = row.xpath('.//td[3]/text()').extract()
            yield {
                "Link": link,
                "Number": number,
                "Date": date,
                "Title": title
            }
```

## pipeline

```
import pymssql


class ScrapingPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymssql.connect(host='localhost', user='sa', password='data1234', database='Sec')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO updates(link, number, date, title) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                            (item['Link'], item['Number'], item['Date'], item['Title']))
        self.conn.commit()


    return item
```

## settings

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'Scraping.pipelines.ScrapingPipeline': 300}
```

## items

```
from scrapy import item, Field

class ScrapingItem(scrapy.Item):
    link = scrapy.Field()
    number = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: Please add the result that is expected of the code

Comment: Which result? The data is getting extracted but not being stored in SQL database.

Comment: If you add something like `spider.logger.info("inside process_item(%r)" % item)` at the start of `process_item`, does it appear in your logs?

Comment: Sorry..I just noticed that the below error is appearing                                              File "pymssql.pyx", line 464, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:7491)
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near ','.DB-Lib error message
 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Serv
er\n")